# Looping through jar in bash and storing console o/p in csv file

Tags: java, sh

I have a shell script as follows. For some reason the `op.csv` file is not generated if there are multiple json files, i.e. `java -jar` is run multiple times within the for loop. However, if `java -jar` is run only once then the `op.csv` files gets created fine. Why is that?

```sh
for filename in $curr_dir/op/*.json; do
 java -jar SCSVGEN.jar "$filename" >> 'op.csv'
 sleep 2
done
```